# Implementing a design pattern in a Database project

Tags: java, database, design-patterns

I am at my last year at the university and working on my final project with a group of friends.

I am responsible on implementing the database (using google firestore in java) and i am trying to implement it using a design pattern.

I found the adapter quiet useful, as I can create an interface called:
GenericDB, which contains all the methods the database needs to use.

A concrete class, let's call her FirestoreDB which implements it,
and an Adapter, which also implements the GenericDB, and holds an Instance Of GenericDB as a variable, so I can choose at run time which db I will want to use (maybe in the future the db would change)

Here is some basic code:

```
public interface GenericDB {

    boolean add(String... args);

    boolean delete(String... args);

    boolean get(String... args);

    boolean changePassword(String... args);

}

public class FirestoreDB implements GenericDB {
    private final Firestore db;
    public FirestoreDB() {
        FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
                FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
                        .setProjectId(Constants.PROJECT_ID)
                        .build();
        this.db = firestoreOptions.getService();
    }

    public boolean add(String... args) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean delete(String... args) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean get(String... args) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean changePassword(String... args) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Adapter implements GenericDB {

    private GenericDB db;
    public Adapter(GenericDB db){
        this.db = db;
    }
    public boolean add(String... args) {
        return this.db.add(args);
    }

    public boolean delete(String... args) {
        return db.delete(args);
    }

    public boolean get(String... args) {
        return db.get(args);
    }

    public boolean changePassword(String... args) {
        return db.changePassword(args);
    }
}

public class DatabaseCreator {
    public GenericDB getDB(DATABASE database) {
        switch (database) {
            case FIRESTORE:
                return new FirestoreDB();
            default:
                return null;
    }
}

DatabaseCreator database = new DatabaseCreator();
GenericDB db = database.getDB(EXTRA.DATABASE.FIRESTORE);
Adapter ad = new Adapter(db);
System.out.println(ad.add("1"));
```

Is this a good use of the adapter pattern?

Comment: This looks more like a question for [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). From the experience I have made, I find the signatures of the methods off. For `get(...)`, I would expect to get the fetched entity back. I would also expect to get the persisted/deleted entity back when calling `.add(...)` or `.delete(...)`. Furthermore, the `switch` within the `DatabseCreator` is a smell. To extend it, one wohld have to modify the source code. On top of this, it would be nice if the interface would be JPA-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Command Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) it more flexible than Adapter in your case

Example:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// demo for firestore
class Firestore {

    private Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(Object id, Object object) {
        map.put(id, object);
    }

    public Object get(Object id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }

}

interface FirestoreAware {

    void setFirestore(Firestore firestore);

}

enum CommandType {
    ADD,
    DELETE,
    GET,
    CHANGE_PASSWORD,
    GET_USER
}

interface Command {

    CommandType getType();

}

class GetCommand implements Command {

    private int id;

    public GetCommand id(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public CommandType getType() {
        return CommandType.GET;
    }
}

class AddCommand implements Command {

    private int id;
    private String jsonData;

    public AddCommand id(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public AddCommand jsonData(String jsonData) {
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
        return this;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getJsonData() {
        return jsonData;
    }

    @Override
    public CommandType getType() {
        return CommandType.ADD;
    }
}

interface CommandHandler<C> {
    Object handle(C cmd);
}

abstract class CommandFirestoreHandler<C>
        implements CommandHandler<C>, FirestoreAware {

    protected Firestore firestore;

    @Override
    public void setFirestore(Firestore firestore) {
        this.firestore = firestore;
    }
}

class AddCommandHandler extends CommandFirestoreHandler<AddCommand> {

    @Override
    public Object handle(AddCommand cmd) {
        firestore.add(cmd.getId(), cmd.getJsonData());
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}

class GetCommandHandler extends CommandFirestoreHandler<GetCommand> {

    @Override
    public Object handle(GetCommand cmd) {
        return firestore.get(cmd.getId());
    }
}

interface GenericDB {

    <T> T execute(Command cmd);

}

class FirestoreDB implements GenericDB {

    private final Firestore firestore;
    private final Map<CommandType, CommandHandler> handlers;

    public FirestoreDB() {
        this(new Firestore());
    }

    public FirestoreDB(Firestore firestore) {
        this.firestore = firestore;
        this.handlers = new HashMap<>();

        // demo add default command handlers
        this.addHandler(CommandType.ADD, new AddCommandHandler());
        this.addHandler(CommandType.GET, new GetCommandHandler());
    }

    public void addHandler(CommandType commandType, CommandHandler handler) {
        if(handler instanceof FirestoreAware)
            ((FirestoreAware)handler).setFirestore(firestore);
        this.handlers.put(commandType, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(Command cmd) {
        CommandHandler handler = handlers.get(cmd.getType());
        return (T)handler.handle(cmd);
    }
}

class DatabaseCreator {
    public GenericDB getDB(String database) {
        switch (database) {
            case "FIRESTORE":
                return new FirestoreDB();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

public class GenericDBDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatabaseCreator database = new DatabaseCreator();
        GenericDB db = database.getDB("FIRESTORE");
        db.execute(new AddCommand().id(1).jsonData("{'_id': 1, 'name' : 'hello world'}"));
        System.out.println(db.execute(new GetCommand().id(1)).toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Request encapsulation is not more or less flexible than converting interfaces. They have different intents.

Comment: @dung ta van There is a problem with this design, suppose I want to get 100 users from the database. I need to make 100 get commands with different id's, because each user has a different id, so the constructor must get a unique id each time,
Same with the add command, each time I need to add a new user I need to make a new add command for a new email and password.

Comment: I only create an example for you, if you want to fetch a list of users you can create a new command, example ```GET_LIST```, ```class GetListCommand implements Command``` and pass a set of user ids, if you need an example, I can edit above source code

Comment: My point was, Consider the option where I would call get command seperately 100 times, each time for another user (that's the point of the command, get one user at a time), won't I have to create 100 new get commands, each for one user? I Just can't seem to see the solution...

Comment: yes, do you worry about performance?, don't worry, it's very cheap.

Comment: @dungtavan I don't worry about performance, rather on clean and nice code. I want to implement it in a way, where when My program gets as a parameter the Command get with the id of the user, the database would execute the command, or the Add command with the id, email etc, it would also execute.

Comment: don't worry about that, Command Design Pattern will bring 'clean and nice code' to you. For each command, if you have many parameters need to pass to query, setter function will make meaning and clean, if you need add more new functions to 'GenericDB', you only need create new 'Command' class and 'Handler' for its (for Adapter Pattern you need modify 2 class 'GenericDB' and 'Adapter'). If you familiar S.O.L.I.D principles, Command Pattern will help you get the 'Open Close' principle. I still have used Command Pattern for my nosql DB project(dahlia)

Comment: If you want to refer, plz take a look: https://github.com/youngmonkeys/dahlia/tree/master/dahlia-core/src/main/java/com/tvd12/dahlia/core/command

Comment: @dungtavan I'm sorry for troubling you, I have seen you'r implementation and tried to study from it. I still have issues with implementing the command in my code. Suppose I want to use the GetCommand, I can't just pass it an id, because I need the Firestore variable to access the google's database, and use the string I gave as a parameter to get the data, HOWEVER, I can't pass a Firestore concrete variable, because I want to make an Interface for GenericDB, and that kills everything, because I can't pass as a parameter the concrete class...

Comment: @dungtavan it happens right here:                                                          
        DatabaseCreator database = new DatabaseCreator();
        GenericDB db = database.getDB("FIRESTORE");
        System.out.println(db.execute(new GetCommand().id(1)).toString());             I can't make the db.execute, because the GetCommand requires also the Firestore db variable (which is inside the FirestoreDB), but then again, I don't want to use concrete classes,but work with abstraction as I don't know which               Database I will choose in the future. any advice for that?...

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good use of the adapter pattern?

What you call Adapter, is not an Adapter. Purpose of Adapter is to *convert interface* of the class to another interface expected by the client. But your 'adapter' implements the same `GenericDB` interface as the adaptee it wraps - no conversion happens here.

The closest one to Adapter is your `FirestoreDB` class. It is intended to convert the interface of `Firestore` to the interface `GenericDB` required by your code. Of course there is still small chance that Google will change `Firestore` to implement your `GenericDB` interface. Until then you should use an adapter.

To make `FirestoreDB` a proper adapter, you should pass adaptee (`Firestore` object) to the constructor of adapter, and later call it in the `GenericDB` methods implementation:

```
public class FirestoreAdapter implements GenericDB {
    private final Firestore db;
    public FirestoreAdapter(Firestore db) { // pass adaptee to adapter
        this.db = db;
    }

    public boolean add(...) {
        // DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(colName).document(docId);
        // etc
    }

    // etc
}
```

This adapter could be passed to the code which expects `GenericDB` interface and knows nothing about `Firestore` interface:

```
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
      FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
                      .setProjectId(Constants.PROJECT_ID)
                      .build();
Firestore firestore = firestoreOptions.getService(); // but your code requires GenericDB
GenericDB db = new FirestoreAdapter(firestore); // adapt Firestore interface
// use db here as if Firestore was implementing your GenericDB interface
```

You can write adapters for another type of database in the same way. But... usually, you don't use some abstract database interface, because databases are very different with different sets of features. Trying to find some intersection of features supported by all databases might be not a great idea (unless you writing CosmosDB). Usually, you will work with higher-level abstractions, like Repositories.

Comment: The type of databases I intend to work on is NO sql, I know that firestore and mongodb stores the data in collection, so they both can get the same parameters :) The only thing that changes is the implementation itself of the insert operation, which happens in thhe FirestoreAdatper, or any other adapter, am I right?